# Java PathIterator - How do I accurately calculate center of Shape object?

Tags: java, shapes, centroid, path-iterator

I am trying to use the PathIterator to calculate the center of any Shape object, so that curved paths can be accounted for, but upon finding the center of a standard 1x1 rectangle, my getCenter() method returns the point:

```
Point2D.Double[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]
```

My getCenter() method:

```
shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 1, 1);


public Point2D.Double getCenter()
        {
            ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();
            double[] arr = new double[6];
            for(PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null); !pi.isDone(); pi.next())
            {
                pi.currentSegment(arr);
                points.add(new Point2D.Double(arr[0], arr[1]));
            }

            double cX = 0;
            double cY = 0;
            for(Point2D.Double p : points)
            {
                cX += p.x;
                cY += p.y;
            }
                    System.out.println(points.toString());
            return new Point2D.Double(cX / points.size(), cY / points.size());
        }
```

I have discovered that upon printing points.toString(), I get this in the Console:

```
[Point2D.Double[0.0, 0.0], Point2D.Double[1.0, 0.0], Point2D.Double[1.0, 1.0], Point2D.Double[0.0, 1.0], Point2D.Double[0.0, 0.0], Point2D.Double[0.0, 0.0]]
```

I noticed that there are six entries in the points array, as opposed to four which I was expecting, given that the input Shape object is Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 1, 1). Obviously it is accounting for the point (0, 0) two more times than I want it to, and I am confused as to why that is. Is it a result of the PathIterator.isDone() method? Am I using it incorrectly? What would solve my problem if PathIterator can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already pointed out, the PathIterator returns different types of segments. When only considering the points that are involved in SEG_LINETO, you should already obtain satisfactory results. However, consider that there may also be SEG_QUADTO and SEG_CUBICTO in other shapes. These can easily be avoided by using a *flattening* PathIterator: When you create a PathIterator with

```
PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null, flatness);
```

with an appropriate flatness, then it will only contain straight line segments.

```
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class ShapeCenter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(computeCenter(new Ellipse2D.Double(-10,-10,20,20)));
        System.out.println(computeCenter(new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,1,1)));
    }

    public static Point2D computeCenter(Shape shape)
    {
        final double flatness = 0.1;
        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null, flatness);
        double coords[] = new double[6];
        double sumX = 0;
        double sumY = 0;
        int numPoints = 0;
        while (!pi.isDone())
        {
            int s = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            switch (s)
            {
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    // Ignore
                    break;

                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    sumX += coords[0]; 
                    sumY += coords[1]; 
                    numPoints++;
                    break;

                case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                    // Ignore
                    break;

                case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                    throw new AssertionError(
                        "SEG_QUADTO in flattening path iterator");
                case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                    throw new AssertionError(
                        "SEG_CUBICTO in flattening path iterator");
            }
            pi.next();
        }
        double x = sumX / numPoints;
        double y = sumY / numPoints;
        return new Point2D.Double(x,y);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[PathIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html) defines different types of segments, you should pay attention to this fact. You get 6 segments in your example, because it returns additionally also the SEG_MOVETO segment, which defines the start of a subpath, and SEG_CLOSE at the end of the sub path. If you just want to get the endpoints of the lines of your shape, you should change your code like this:

```
    for(PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null); !pi.isDone(); pi.next())
    {
        if(pi.currentSegment(arr) == PathIterator.SEG_LINETO) {
            points.add(new Point2D.Double(arr[0], arr[1]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you're using it *incorrectly* but you aren't accounting for an aspect of [PathIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html). PathIterator doesn't so much represent a geometric shape but rather a path that should be taken while drawing. So its points also represent the type of path the 'pen' should take. For example, for a Rectangle, the path makes the following segments:

1. `SEG_MOVETO`
2. `SEG_LINETO`
3. `SEG_LINETO`
4. `SEG_LINETO`
5. `SEG_LINETO`
6. `SEG_CLOSE`

Because obviously the path should:

- Move, not draw, from wherever the pen was before.
- Close off this path from whatever the pen draws next.

The type of segment is the return value of `currentSegment`. If you only want to capture points that are on the polygon you can check for the 'line to' segment:

```
if(pi.currentSegment(arr) == PathIterator.SEG_LINETO) {
    points.add(new Point2D.Double(arr[0], arr[1]));
}
```

That will work for simple polygons like Rectangle. For the given Rectangle, it will return [0.5, 0.5] which is I assume the result you're interested in.

On the other hand, there are Shapes that are not polygons so I'd be careful with this approach.